# increase a field value based on the radio button selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> .

This is my whole code to implment the survey in views. if i give the count as third argument in radio button i cant select answer for each question. i can select only one answer for the whole survey.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using virtual attributes.

```
attr_accessor :count_modification
before_save :modify_count

def modify_count()
    self.count += @count_modification if @count_modification
end
```

And in view:

```
<%= radio_button("my_model", "count_modification", "1") %> Add one vote
<%= radio_button("my_model", "count_modification", "2") %> Add 2 votes
<%= radio_button("my_model", "count_modification", "3") %> Add 3 votes
```

This way, the votes won't be updated than after the model is saved.

Comment: if i get the radio button id from loop, where i can place it
ex:
<%=radio_button(count, :nominees, :vote_modification) %>

Comment: the count value will be increased for each cycle.

Comment: Modified my answer to take this into account :)

Comment: what ever changes i have made, the values are not updating in database.